Wordpress issue error regarding mixed content. Pulled CSS from wrong url?
I am having an issue with wordpress, the error message I am receiving is.

admin.php:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://communalfire.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=blc_local&filter_id=redirects' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.busterrhinos.com/?ver=640'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Where communalfire.com is the current site
Where busterrhinos.com is an old site I haven't had on my servers for years. Where would it be pulling that information from? I have several admin pages that won't serve anything up to me and I think this might be the cause.
Ideas on how to fix this?
I've downloaded a link checker, also SSL Secure content checker that looks for secure content problems. It's only in the admin areas that I am currently experiencing this. Found it while installing indexNow.

Hello Darryl,
This sounds like hard-coded URLs within a custom theme or a plugin that is implemented on the site. It may also be that this URL is in the database and is displayed on a page. A search and replace tool would then help to replace this URL in the database.
If there are hardcoded elements within the theme or plugin, a developer would have to take a closer look at them.

I appreciate the reply, I have already figured it out and when I put the answer up so that if someone else had the problem it waas deleted by a moderator. Not sure why. Anyway, it was an old htaccess file that was causing it. Removed it and voila, all fixed.
